# Space key is working weird in Visual Studio Code on mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, tabs, keyboard, space

In Visual Studio Code on a mac (in my windows pc no problem with vscode), after I typed one word then want a space, the focus automatically goes to the suggestions or simply freeze there. I tried all the method I can find online and nothing worked. When I press tab in vs code, sometimes it works. Most of the time, it just moves the focus to other place or does nothing. But I don't have the problem in atom. It's super frustrating, I uploaded my screen recording in youtube here: https://youtu.be/nMMFlYxbNL0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I installed iTem2, the space key won't work at all unless I press shift+space, then I found solution by searching this 'iTem2' particular question online, it turns out just the **Full Keyboard Access** needs to be turned off, then everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

Shut Down the Mac for few hours then restart,It will work perfectly.This technique worked for me.Trust me :)

Comment: Is "turn your computer off for a few hours" really a reasonable solution to this?